# Python script hangs in loop

Tags: python, loops, freeze

In one of my scripts I'm using the following infinite loop to check for an active internet connection:

```
def online_check():
    try:
        con = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
        data = con.read()
        logging.debug('{0} Reached the host. Exiting online_check'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
    except:
        logging.debug('{0} Could not reach host trying again in 3 seconds'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
        time.sleep(3)
        online_check()
```

I am aware that this is not a very elegant solution but the problem is that when I start my script it will sometimes call the online_check method and get stuck in the middle of it (Once in roughly 200 attempts). The script is still running and no exception is thrown; the script is just stuck. I can press CTRL+C (Even after hours of the script being stuck) and it will just throw an exception and continue with the next online_check. I also rewrote the script to check for an IP address in 'ifconfig' as opposed to pinging google, unfortunately with similar results.

What am I doing wrong? Can I rewrite the script so this never happens? Is there something I can do to find out what is happening here?

Help is greatly appreciated. Btw. I'm using Python2.7.1 and I've tried this script both on Linux and Mac.

P.S: If you have recommendations for designing a method that checks for connectivity without using bandwidth and minimal overhead, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't overflow the callstack!

Comment: Could you explain that to me Gordon? you just overflowed my brainstack..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow for more info, but the basic idea is that every time you call a function you have to push a new frame onto the call stack, and that takes memory, and eventually you'll run out of call stack and crash.  Literally a stack overflow.  You picked the right site to ask this question on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the infinite recursion (CPython as far as I'm aware doesn't support optimized tail-end recursion), you are not closing your connection.

You might be hitting some kind of connection limit either with the OS or with Google when it retries.  This probably happens before reaching max recursion depth which is why you don't get an exception.

The connection would normally close when it get garbage collected, but I think because of the recursion the variable doesn't completely go out of scope until the recursion ends.

Also as @senderle mentioned, you should try to catch a more specific error.

Try:

```
def online_check():
  while True:
    try:
      con = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
      data = con.read()
      logging.debug('{0} Reached the host. Exiting online_check'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
    except urllib2.URLError:
      logging.debug('{0} Could not reach host trying again in 3 seconds'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
      time.sleep(3)
    finally:
      con.close()
```

(Warning untested code)

Comment: @nick I also incorporated what @senderle said about catching a more specific error because you should always catch the most specific one that works.  Otherwise you're just hiding other errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are running into infinite recursion, a method you can do to not have this happen is pass an argument into online_check for the maximum check.

Such as:

```
def online_check(max_checks=10, current_check=0):
    try:
        con = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
        data = con.read()
        logging.debug('{0} Reached the host. Exiting online_check'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
    except:
        logging.debug('{0} Could not reach host trying again in 3 seconds'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
        if max_checks > current_check:
          time.sleep(3)
          online_check(max_checks, current_check+1)
```

So  you would do:

```
online_check(5) # for 5 maximum checks
online_check() # use the default value, which is 10
```

I also suggest you catch more specific exceptions, for better coding habits but also because when you do CTRL-C, Python throws a KeyboardInterrupt exception, which your code actually catches because you catch all exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what happens since the method is called on average 4 times before it exits. It usually gets stuck after only 3 runs. Could this be still related to recursion depth? Wouldn't there be an exception?

Comment: Regardless, you are doing recursion and you always need a reliable base case to cancel the recursion. You may be correct that urlopen() or read() is just hanging, however you should implement your reliable base case(i.e. not depending on no exception thrown).

Comment: well, he does have a base case, albeit not a very good one.  The base case is when there is no exception thrown.  If python optimized tail-call recursion into a loop it would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to others' suggestions, you should really specify which exception(s) you're catching. Control-C doesn't work because that just raises an exception, and your `except` statement interprets it as being the same as all others.

Seems like the exception you want is `urllib2.URLError`.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know that about Ctrl-C (and also because it's true, you should never just catch all types of exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

At some point this program is going to end up encountering the recursion depth limit for your interpreter.  Typically, a function that should continuously run would be structured like so:

```
def online_check():
  while True:
    try:
      con = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
      data = con.read()
      logging.debug('{0} Reached the host. Exiting online_check'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
      break
    except:
      logging.debug('{0} Could not reach host trying again in 3 seconds'.format(time.strftime('[ %H:%M:%S ]')))
      time.sleep(3)
```

That should give you better results.  I imagine you've already got a separate thread that's running this function (otherwise later code can't execute - this function never returns).

Comment: No separate thread and code does execute after I call this method. Should I put in a return after the online_check is successful? Why would you need it?

Comment: the function does return. It returns when theres no exception.  Recursion only happens on failure.